# Creating Object in EF which is null after saveChanges in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

after i set the AuditReport on my Audit and save it, (in Debugger it is filled with a Proxy) there is still no Entry in the Database and I have no Idea why. Here are the relevant classes:

```
public class AuditReport
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Audit")]
    [Column("AuditReport_ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Audit Audit { get; set; }
}

public class Audit
{
    [Key]
    public int GeneratedID { get; set; }

    [Index("Audit_ID", IsUnique = true)]
    public int Audit_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual AuditReport AuditReport { get; set; }
}
```

And the method in that the new AuditReport is Created

```
public async override Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
   using (var dbAccess = new DatabaseAccess())
   {
        var foundAudit = dbAccess.Audits.Include("AuditReport").Include("AuditReport.Stellungnahmen").SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Audit_ID == Audit.Audit_ID);
        if (foundAudit != null)
        {
            if (foundAudit.AuditReport == null)
            {
                foundAudit.AuditReport = dbAccess.AuditReports.Create();
                foundAudit.AuditReport.Audit = foundAudit;
            }                      
            else
            foundAudit.AuditReport.Stellungnahmen.ToList().ForEach(_ => dbAccess.Entry(_).State = EntityState.Deleted);

            foreach (var item in Stellungnahmen.Where(_ => _.IsChecked == true))
                    foundAudit.AuditReport.Stellungnahmen.Add(dbAccess.Stellungnahmen.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.KeyWord == item.KeyWord));
            }
        await dbAccess.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

As i already said, I've already debugged it and everything looks fine.

Comment: make sure you're calling `.Commit()` in your dbcontext.

Comment: I have no transaction running. Commit is a method of transaction

Comment: you are not actually adding the entries to the context, but are only setting the navigation properties. So your related entries are in the context, but in an unchanged state, so EF won't create any queries for this. Set their EntityState to Added if they are correctly in the DbSet's of the context.

Comment: Sry, my boss decided to put all the Propertys in the same class to not waste any more time on this problem #feelsBadMan

Comment: Try to remove [Key] on ID.

Comment: @ShawnYan Post it as answer, I'll mark it as solution. Thanks alot.
Exception was: `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `[Key]` on ID since you already have `[ForeignKey]` atrribute.

Comment: Works. After that I looked at the right places for an issue: Exception was `` `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`